# Java get the variable on the fly vs storing it

Tags: java, performance

Are there any performance boost by writing:

```
final double x = objectClass.getMyDouble();
myLogger.log(x);
```

to

```
myLogger.log(objectClass.getMyDouble());
```

I think it improves the runtime a little bit by writing the second way. If it does, how is it able to improve the runtime?

Comment: Have you measured it? If the difference is measurable, you'll be able to see it... if it's not (which is what I strongly suspect) then you'll see no difference. It's almost *always* worth optimising for readability first, and only move away from readability when you can *measure* the performance benefit.

Comment: There could be a "boost" if x is reused later in the code. Your example only adds an extra assignment to the code. Anyway, don't worry about Java/JVM performance until you hit a real problem. The JVM makes performance enhancement, probably you never heard about.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no difference at runtime. The local final variable (or effectively final - the compiler can very easily tell) will be [optimised by inlining it](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=compiler-how-jit-optimizes-code).

More interestingly, a decent logging framework (eg log4j) will lazily evaluate messages dependent on the logging level - this does provide material performance improvements.

For example, with

```
logger.debug("Amount: {}", objectClass.getMyDouble());
```

Log4j can check the Log-Level first and then decide if its necessary to construct the message string. This saves resources needed for string concatenation. It will only call `toString()` on the objects supplied if the message is actually being created, saving further computation costs.